How do i get rid of this error and prevent the code to run for infinetly amount of time
Below is my code:
public class Practice_3 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Question-1:
                //****
                //***
                //**
                //*
        String str ="*";
        int n =4;
        for(int i=n; i>0; i--){
            for (int j=i; j<=i;j--){
                System.out.print(str);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}

Whenever , i try to run it , it kept on running infinelty.

Take a look at inner for-loop for (int j=i; j<=i;j--), when will this condition become false?

j is always ≤ i in your code.
Replace with j > 0
Full code
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "*";
        int n = 4;
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(str);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}



Unless you are required to use nested loops, here are a couple alternatives.  Both use String.repeat for different purposes.

the first simply prints the asterisk repeated i times as you loop in reverse.
the second builds the string to its maximum size and then prints substrings starting at i incrementing towards n

String str ="*";
int n =4;
for (int i =n; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(str.repeat(i));
}

// or

str = "*".repeat(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(i));
}

